# Accessing indexed element of a list, where the list is a value of a python dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

i Have a dictionary where the values are list, i have something like this:

```
dic = {"A":[6,4,7,10], "B":[8,10,90,100]}
```

how do i access the element 7 from the list where the key is "A"?

Comment: How would you access `7` when you have just the list? And how would you access just the value given by the `'A'` key? You can trivially combine those two.

Comment: `dic['A'][2]` should work

Comment: Also, Python comes with an interactive interpreter; just plug in the line from your question and *try things out*.

Comment: @NendoTaka thank you it works; i didnt know that we can have two indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an extra index like `dic['A'][2]`